# How can I fix that the app bar hide part of my content

Tags: android, android-layout

I created app bar, and underneath that my recycler view -

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />


 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The problem is that the Toolbar hide the top content of my recycler view.

I tried to set my recycler view constraint to   `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="my_toolbar"`, But doesn't work.

What is the problem with my code?

**UPDATE**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1afr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for toolbar use:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

and for the recyclerview use:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you Toolbar overlays the RecyclerView as it uses elevation and your RecyclerView is set to top of parent. The obvious solution is:

Change this -> `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

to `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"`

You were possibly using `my_toolbar` instead of `@id/my_toolbar`.

Also, remember, Unlike other Layouts, `ConstraintLayout` uses after declared view on top approach means the views at bottom comes on top. So, if the sequence is View A then View B then View B will be on top and in other layouts, it's vice-versa.

Comment: Indeed it's the obvious solution, but weridly it didn't do the magic..I updated my question with an image maybe it will help understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In your recyclerview tag instead of `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"`
Finally, remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/movies_recycler_view"` and set it to `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`
this leaves space for your toolbar and the recyclerview will be at the bottom of your toolbar. FYI you can use the Android Studio designer tool to set the recyclerview's top constraint to bottom of your toolbar.